# C++. Link .dll file to project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dll, dynamic-linking

I have created a c++ project with visual studio. Now I want to write a code that creates an .exe file which depends on a .dll file that I want to include in my project directory.

More precisely, I am trying to write a c++ program which opens computers camera and took a picture. For this I want to use OpenCV's library. But I need to link the OpenCV's corresponding .dll files to my project.

Now my question is, how can I link that .dll file in my C++ code?
Also, **I want my project to work on every computer that I will copy the project.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the library to your project in project properties -> linker -> input -> aditional dependencies and edit include and library directories in configuration properties -> vc++ directories or just add this two lines:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libname")
#include "headerlib.h"
```